# Return object of [super Init]

Tags: objective-c

Well...I have read and have done a lot of research on the expression of [super init] in class inheritance of objective-c. Even some of the questions have been well explained and answered on stackoverflow. However, I still don't really understand how inheritance or the [super init] works.

In other languages, the superclass knows nothing about the subclass. There is no way for the superclass to return an object of the subclass because the superclass has no knowledge of the subclass. So my question is if expression self = [super init] return the object of the **SUPERCLASS** or **SUBCLASS**. Here I do know that the [super init] could return another object or nil, which makes sense. But assuming everything works fine and neither is it nil nor return another object. If it returns a regular object, does it return the object of the superclass or derived class, which is the class in which this **self = [super init]** is defined. If it returns an object of the super class, then it makes sense but then since as we know, the object of the superclass knows nothing about the subclass, how can it access the members (fields, messages or methods) of the subclass. If it returns an object of the subclass, then it does not make sense, since there is no way that the superclass can return an object of the derived class because the superclass knows nothing of it.

This is one of the aspects that is really confusing for those who transition from other languages to objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

`self = [super init]`
will return the object from the superclass. However, note that the object itself has likely been allocated using `alloc` on your current class.

Consider the following:

```
@interface A : NSObject
- (instancetype)init;
@end

@interface B : A
- (instancetype)init;
@end

@implementation B
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Do initialization for B
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

When you create a new object of a class `B` you do as follows:

```
B *obj = [[B alloc] init];
```

In turn the following happens:

- `[B alloc]`allocates the object with enough space to hold all of `B`.
- Calls `init` on the newly created object of class `B`.
- Then `init` on class `A` is called from `B`'s init method
- `init` on class `A` will*  return the object allocated with `B`'s `alloc`.

*) Note that the `init` method may return *another* object than the allocated one. This is allowed, and is a reason why you usually should assign the result to `self`.

[Read more - What does it mean when you assign [super init] to self?](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html)

Comment: So you meant when the [super init] is called, the hidden parameter of self that belongs to or of the current class is passed along with it? Otherwise, I cannot see how the superclass could return an object of the subclass. Because like any other languages, the superclass does not know anything about the subclass.

Comment: Yes, all instance methods receive a hidden self parameter when called. Instance methods are declared with an initial ‘-‘, contrary to class methods (like alloc) that start with ‘+’.